# Как проверить все поля таблицы на пустоту используя is not null?

Tags: sql

используя в запросе is not null  для одного поля все работает, добавляю 2 поле и выдает ошибку. Подскажите как мне проверить допустим 30 полей в базе данных на пустоту ?

```
SELECT * FROM `datafrom` where `micur`, `mtimein` is not NULL  OR myid='".$umid."'"
```

Comment: Нужно писать условие для обоих полей отдельно `micur IS NOT NULL OR mtimein IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Используйте логические операторы - `AND` или `OR` в зависимости от того, какое условие Вы хотите. Например `... WHERE micur IS NOT NULL AND mtimein IS NOT NULL ...`

Comment: Если надо проверить на OR (т.е. что есть хотя бы один NOT NULL) - разумнее использовать COALESCE (да ещё расположить поля в порядке убывания вероятности наличия значения). Если надо проверить, что все NOT NULL - можно использовать подходящую для типа данных функцию или оператор (конкатенация строковых, сложение числовых и т.п.).

Answer (score 1):

Функция `COALESCE` вернёт значение первого параметра, который не `null`.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (f1 char, f2 char, f3 char)
/
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('x', null, null);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (null, null, null);

SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE COALESCE(f1, f2, f3) is not null;
```

Вывод:

```
F F F
- - -
x
```